# Question about borrow checker which using the flatmap function

Tags: rust

I am new to rust and coming to grips with how ownership and borrow checking works

I wrote this little function

```
pub fn count_words(file_path: &str) -> Result<usize, Error> {
    return File::open(file_path).map(|file| {
        let reader = BufReader::new(file);
        return reader
            .lines()
            .map(|line| line.unwrap())
            .flat_map(|line| line.split_whitespace())
            .count();
    });
}
```

I get this error

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `line`
  --> src/lib.rs:19:30
   |
19 |             .flat_map(|line| line.split_whitespace())
   |                              ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                              |
   |                              returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |                              `line` is borrowed here
   |
   = help: use `.collect()` to allocate the iterator
```

I am not sure I understand what is happening here (As in which entity is borrowing line so i cant call split whitespace).

I managed to get this version running

```
pub fn count_words(file_path: &str) -> Result<usize, io::Error> {
    return File::open(file_path).map(|file| {
        let reader = BufReader::new(file);
        let lines = reader.lines();
        let mut num_words = 0;
        for line in lines {
            num_words += line.unwrap().split_whitespace().count();
        }
        return num_words
    });
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of extraneous `return` statements in here. Remember Rust has an implicit `return` of the last value, so by adding the `;` on the final statements here you're working against yourself.

Comment: Gotcha. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62243005/how-to-fix-cannot-return-value-referencing-function-parameter-error-in-rust

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust is having trouble here because it creates short-lived references to the `line` you're iterating over that must persist outside of the scope that variable is defined in.

Since you really don't care about the line content, just work with the count directly:

```
BufReader::new(file)
    .lines()
    .map(|line| line.unwrap())
    .map(|line| line.split_whitespace().count())
    .sum()
```

Where you can trivially add up all these split counts. This is roughly what you're doing in your more verbose version, but I think this sort of code reads better in terms of its Rust-ness.

It's pretty obvious here that you can further reduce how much code is here by combining the two `map()` operations into one, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the fact that `.split_whitespace()` returns an iterator that will **refer** to `line` at each iteration, but `line`, which is an owned `String`, will be dropped as soon as the closure returns.

You need to consume every iteration of this iterator while `line` still exists.
Here is another formulation, still with a functional style (instead of explicit loops).

Note that I traded `.unwrap()` for `.ok()` in `.map_while()` in order to avoid a `panic!()` when a line cannot be retrieved.
(Although the downvote does not come with any comment, I guess it is an allusion to this not-triggered [clippy lint](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#/lines_filter_map_ok) in my previous attempt.)

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{BufRead, BufReader, Error},
};

pub fn count_words(file_path: &str) -> Result<usize, Error> {
    Ok(BufReader::new(File::open(file_path)?)
        .lines()
        .map_while(|line| {
            line.ok().map(|line| line.split_whitespace().count())
        })
        .sum())
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", count_words("src/main.rs"))
}
/*
Ok(33)
*/
```